# FabricJS Android Webview Newlines showing as \n

Tags: android-webview, fabricjs

So I load a basic page with the canvas and everything seems to work except newlines are shown as `\n`

here is the body as a java method:

```
input = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeShell(this.getData());

    private String htmlBody(String input){


        return "<html><head>" +
                "<link href=\"fonts.css\" type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" />" +
                "<script src=\"jquery.min.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>" +
                "<script src=\"fontfaceobserver.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>" +
                "<script src=\"fabric.min.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>" +
                "<style type=\"text/css\">" +

                ".canvas-container {" +
                        "margin: 0 auto;" +
                    "}"+
        "</style>" +
                "<script src=\"javascript_fabric.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>" +
                "</head><body>"+
                "<div id=\"sb2div\" class=\"row\" style=\"margin: 0 auto!important; max-height: 100vh\">" +
                "<canvas id=\"fabricjs-branding\" width=\"600\" height=\"600\" style=\"margin: auto!important;\"></canvas>" +
                "</div>" +
                "<script>" +
                "$(document).ready(function(){" +
                    "setUpBranding();" +
                    "var o = " + input + ";" +
                    "console.log(o);" +
                    "fabricjscanvas.loadFromJSON(o);"+
                "});" +
                "</script>" +
                "</body></html>";

    }
```

`setUpBranding()` does my initialization of `fabricjscanvas` which does add some feature prototypes but the issue has nothing to do with them.

itext and textbox are standard using the current release 4

[image: here you can see the \n]

on the desktop using the same setup everything is fine...[image: same json but on the desktop works]

Comment: The same setup obviously isn't. Something is escaping/adding slashes on your string before entering in the function. Where the string comes from?

Comment: the string `input` is unescaped data downloaded from a database see edit in post added the Java line for input at the top. also this is just the string that was saved via desktop browser

Comment: so you are correct it was not getting unescaped so I did it manually with a replace...`input = input.replace("\\\\n", "\\n");` do you know a better way?

Comment: make your comment an answer and I'll mark it as correct

Comment: Don't worrying for make the comment an answer.
Answer yourself with a good answer describing the solution and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on a comment i found the newline characters were not getting unescaped with the rest of the json data... strange but I was able to fix it using the Java String Replace method... after using the `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeShell`

```
input = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeShell(this.getData());
input = input.replace("\\\\n", "\\n");
```